# How does one synchronize the order of an array of reference-items with the precedence of their related element-nodes within the DOM tree by their IDs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, filtering, lookup

how to sort element id by knowing their position in DOM

I have one array of element IDs on the page but this array is not sorted by their position in DOM/page.
I want to sort them by their position on the page.

Array:

```
[{ id:'first', type:'TEXT'},{id:'third',type:'DROPDOWN'},{id:'second',type:'TEXT'}]
```

output:

```
[{id:'first', type:'TEXT'},{id:'second',type:'TEXT'},{id:'third',type:'DROPDOWN'}]
```

Comment: Can the OP also provide he corresponding HTML fragment in order to prevent any misunderstanding from the solution providing side.

Comment: i didn't get that :(
i have page with one form on it, and the response is not getting in sorted order, so i want to sort that array by using DOM

Comment: I'd like to see the HTML code that fits your second sorted array example

Comment: sure give me some time :)

Comment: Hi Peter .. sorry for the delay I was offline for many days due medical issues :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic approach which works across any DOM structure follows this steps ...

1. create a reference-`id` based lookup-table / map / index for any reference which is listed within the unordered array of reference-items. Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for achieving this task.
2. retrieve an array of all element-nodes starting at a root-node of ones own choice by using e.g. [`getElementsByTagName('*')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).
3. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the element-array by existing reference-`id`s while using the reference-lookup as the [filter-function's `this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#description).
4. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the filtered element array of **step 3** back to an array of reference-items by each element's `id` while using again the reference-lookup as the [map-function's `this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters_in_detail); thus preserving the order of the former through mapping this order to the final result.

... and might look similar to the next provided example code ...

```js
const unorderedReferenceList = [
  { id: 'bar', type: 'TEXT' },
  { id: 'baz', type: 'DROPDOWN' },
  { id: 'foo', type: 'TEXT' },
];
console.log({ unorderedReferenceList });

const referenceIndex = unorderedReferenceList
  .reduce((index, reference) => {
    index[reference.id] = reference;
    return index;
  }, {});

console.log({ referenceIndex });

const elementList = Array.from(
  document.body.getElementsByTagName('div')
);
console.log({ elementList });

const filteredElementList = elementList
  .filter(function (elm) {
    return (elm.id in this);
  }, referenceIndex);

console.log({ filteredElementList });

const orderedReferenceList = filteredElementList
  .map(function (elm) {
    return this[elm.id];
  }, referenceIndex);

console.log({ orderedReferenceList });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>

    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div id="foo">foo</div>
      </div>
      <div id="bar">bar</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div>

    <div>
      <div id="baz">baz</div>
      <div></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ShriramSalunkhe ... regarding the above approach, are there any questions left?